# Installing RDKit and using Pandas

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, python3, pandas

this is my first time writing here. I am starting to use RDKit but I found the installation very difficult. I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and python3 (anaconda).

Following the procedures posted at de oficial website of [rdkit](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html) I first try to install rdkit from repositories by:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-rdkit librdkit1 rdkit-data
```

But it goes with errors because python-rdkit is not found:

> Unable to locate package python-rdkit

So I try: `sudo apt-get python3-rdkit` this have installed python3-rdkit but then when I want to use it, it doesn't work. Besides, it is not found among the packages when I check using `conda list`. What is the correct sentence for importing python3-rdkit? Is it the same as rdkit?

Then, I decided to install rdkit as an env following the installation with conda recommendations. It works but it creates an env with python2.7 and pandastools doesn't work properly. Besides, the rdkit version installed is 2017 when the last release is 2020. How can I get installed the latest version of rdkit and using python3 with pandastools working?

I will appreciate any help! Again I have found rdkit dificult to install for a non-programer user. Thanks in advance!